# How do I use the :tag command in vim to toggle between .hpp and the corresponding .cpp?

Tags: c++, vim

**Background**

I got the following hard-coded command to work ok in my `.vimrc`:

```
nmap ,a :tag Foo.cpp<CR>
```

So that if I hit `,a`, vim will look through the ctags cache and open the file `Foo.cpp` from the location specified by the tags file.

**Question**

*How do I modify this command so that if I am looking at `Bar.hpp`, it will lookup `Bar.cpp` and if I am looking at `Bar.cpp`, it will look up `Bar.hpp`?*

AFAIK, there are many ways to skin this cat, but I would prefer to use the `:tag` command somehow since it is **fast** and I am already generating the tags file anyways.

Comment: I'm going to leave this right here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easily_switch_between_source_and_header_file

Comment: @PeterRincker ty - I did come across that link while googling - in fact, I have used a.vim before, but for some reason, I had trouble configuring the search path correctly this time.  So I posted this question in search of a simple, easy-to-understand/maintain solution.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for my simple cases:

```
function! OtherName()
        if expand('%:e') == "cpp"
                return substitute( expand('%:t'), "cpp", "hpp", "" )
        elseif expand('%:e') == "hpp"
                return substitute( expand('%:t'), "hpp", "cpp", "" )
        endif
endfunction
nmap ,a :execute "tag" OtherName()<CR>
```

There could be some ugliness if hpp or cpp actually shows up in the filename - perhaps I need to use regex to tighten up the substitute.  Also, if we are in a non cpp or hpp file, things could get ugly.

Perhaps there are more experienced vimscripters out there who can improve on the robustness of this code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of a solution found on the vim wiki, [Easily switch between source and header file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easily_switch_between_source_and_header_file).

```
nnoremap ,a :tag %:t:s,.hpp$,.X123X,:s,.cpp$,.hpp,:s,.X123X$,.cpp,<CR>
```

The basic idea is to switch `.hpp` for `.cpp` and vice versa based on the current filename, `%`.

For more information see:

```
:h :_%
:h filename-modifiers
```